# How is it possible for a block to appear only if cms page is set as home page

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, home

In the content  of a cms page I add a (non cms) block

```
{{block type="A/B" template="xxx/xxx.phtml"}}
```

If cms page is set as home page is ok

If is not set as home page is not appearing

Obviously I miss something but what ?Any ideas ?

> Myslider.php

```
class Mytheme_Myslider_Block_Myslider extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getDataSlides()
    {
        $data_slides  = Mage::getModel('Myslider/Myslider')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);

        $data=$data_slides->toArray();
        $filtered_data=array();
        if(count($data['items']))
        foreach($data['items'] as $slide)
        {
            $stores=explode(',',$slide['store_id']);
            if(in_array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(),$stores) || in_array(0,$stores))$filtered_data[]=$slide;
        }

        return $filtered_data;
    }

    public function getDataSlider()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('Myslider'))$this->setData('Myslider', Mage::registry('Myslider'));
        else return $this->getData('Myslider');

    }

}
```

> myslider.phtml

```
<div id="slider_top">

<ul class="rslides" id="carousel1">

    <?php
    $slides = $this->getDataSlides();
    foreach($slides as $slide)
    {
    ?>

         <li>
          <div class="overlap_widget_wrapper">
            <div class="left_image">
              <div class="placeholder"><a href="<?php echo $slide['link'];?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $slide['image'];?>" alt="" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_image">
              <div class="placeholder"><a href="<?php echo $slide['link_1'];?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $slide['image1'];?>" alt="" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </li>

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: can you shod the content of the block class and/or template ?

Comment: you want all page right?

Comment: do you want that block for all cms pages?

Comment: I added both php and phtml @Marius

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a block to all CMS page.

Use the below code in your `local.xml` file or in your module layout file.

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="A/B" name="your.unique.name" template="xxx/xxx.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

Or if you want to add only for home page use

`cms_index_index` handle(replace `cms_page` with `cms_index_index`) in above code

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than using those ugly tags/variables as mentioned in the start post.

Comment: This is what I have done in first place in cms.xml but the problem remains. I placed it in local.xml and is not solved. This looks strange Is there a way to enable or disable a module per page to look if this is the problem ?